# how to handle multiple button click in react, to know which is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I would like to know how to handle button  click events in multiple places.

I have `Button` component, used in `Home` Component multiple times,
When button clicked, it shows Image but are displayed in all places 
How to handle click events in multiple places,

```
class Button extends React.PureComponent{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
  }
  render(){
  return(
    <button onClick={()=>this.props.toggle();}>Click Me</button>);
  }
}

class Button extends React.PureComponent{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
    this.state={
    showImage: true
   }
  }

toggle(){
  this.setState({
    showImage: !this.state.showImage
  })
}

  render(){
    return(
     <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <Button onClick={this.toggle}/>
        {this.state.showImage===true ? <img src="xyz.jpg"/> : ""}
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <Button onClick={this.toggle}/>
         {this.state.showImage===true ? <img src="xyz.jpg"/> : ""}
      </div>
     </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Does both classes are named as Button?

Comment: Do you want these buttons and images to toggle independently?

Comment: @CameronDowner yes, on button it should only images independently

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan yes

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the state holding the visibility of the image into a child component. This component would be responsible for 1 image, 1 button and the state of that image.

```
function ToggleableImage({ imageSrc }) {
  const [isVisible, setVisibility] = React.useState(true);

  function toggleVisibility() {
    setVisibility(currentVisibility => !currentVisibility);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggleVisibility} />
      {isVisible && <img src={imageSrc} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This component takes in the image you want to display as a prop. It has the `isVisibile` state and a `toggleVisibility` function for updating the state which is called by the button.

I have used [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) and [React hooks for the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), but the idea of dropping the state to a child component is the same.

You can then add multiple of these components to the parent.

```
function Images() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <ToggleableImage imageSrc="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <ToggleableImage imageSrc="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[You can see this working here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mccarthy-zrw5n)